# MVC and Sitefinity api

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sitefinity-8

I am working on a project that needs to update data in a Sitefinity database.  I added the Telerik.Sitefinity_All dll's to the project.  I've added the connection string to the database that contains all the sitefinity data.  I'm trying to use the API for sitefinity to connect to the database and pull the data but I'm having troubles.  How do you configure the App.WorksWith() to use the connection for the sitefinity database, or is there any good documentation showing how to fully set this up?  Thanks in advance for any help, I'm extremely new to Sitefinity.  FYI, this is using Sitefinity v 9.2

Answer (score 1):

Presuming the site builds and runs fine here is what you need to do in order to be able to create a custom Web Api service which will use the Sitefinity API and will allow the web api to be called from external applications:

1. Register a custom route - this is done in Global asax file. See example below:

   ```
   protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       SystemManager.ApplicationStart += SystemManager_ApplicationStart;
   }

   private void SystemManager_ApplicationStart(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {            
       RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
   }

   private void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
   {
       routes.Ignore("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

       routes.MapHttpRoute(
           name: "DefaultApi",
           routeTemplate: "ajax/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
           defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });
   }
   ```

Here I am using the /ajax/ route because /api/ is already taken by Sitefinity in 9.2.

2. Create your web api controller and use the Sitefinity API inside:

   ```
   public class CourseController : ApiController
   {
       [HttpPost]
       public HttpResponseMessage CreateOrUpdateCourse([FromBody] Course item)
       { 
       // use Sitefinity API here
       // if you need to make modifications to the data then you need to use the ElevatedModeRegion   }}
   ```